# Create chained flutter animation with multiple images

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I would like to create a widget with an animation composed of showing a sequence of images fading in and out with a repeat after complete. Something like this attached animation:

[image: flutter animation]

Since I'm new to Flutter, I would like to know what is the best approach to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with `AnimatedSwitcher` widget. It's one of Flutter's easy-to-use implicit animation widgets. Its main job is to automatically create a cross-fade transition when its child widget changes.

You can see it in action by changing the string below, and do a hot reload. You will see a cross fade transition for 200 ms:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  child: Text(
    'Hello', // manually change the text here, and hot reload
    key: UniqueKey(),
  ),
)
```

Once you understand how `AnimatedSwitcher` works, you can decide how to loop through the list images. For simplicity, I'm giving you an example using texts, but the idea is the same.

Full source code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final Timer timer;

  final values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() => _index++);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          child: Text(
            values[_index % values.length],
            key: UniqueKey(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html). After setup animation controller, you just call the [repeat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController/repeat.html) function. The animation will be going to a limitless loop. With [AnimationStatusListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationLocalStatusListenersMixin/addStatusListener.html) you can change color and title text.