# Flutter : create animation from list of many images

Tags: flutter, flame

I have 50 images, that each represent the state of an animation, at very short intervals. Like a sprite which shows a little guy swinging an axe.

I need to do a very simple thing : create an animation in flutter that shows this animation.

I found 2 solutions:

- [AnimatedSwitcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532048/create-chained-flutter-animation-with-multiple-images)

But I fear this would be too slow for such short time intervals?

- [Flutter Flame](https://flame-engine.org/) which contains ways to animate a sprite

But it feels way over-engineered for my simple use case

What is the correct way to do that in flutter, and have a smooth animation?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/spritewidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flame's `SpriteAnimationWidget` for this.

Since Flutter has tree shaking you don't have to worry about Flame being a large library, everything you don't use will be cleaned away when you build your app.

To use the `SpriteAnimationWidget` simple do this:

```dart
SpriteAnimationWidget.asset(
  path: 'your_spritesheet.png',
  data: SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
    amount: 50,
    stepTime: 0.1,
    textureSize: Vector2(32, 32),
  ),
);
```

This is if your 50 images are in a spritesheet, if they are not, you can do this:

```dart
final sprites = images.map((image) => Sprite(image)).toList();
SpriteAnimationWidget(
  animation: SpriteAnimation.spriteList(
    sprites,
    stepTime: 0.1,
  ),
);
```

where `images` would be a list of your `Image` objects.

0.1 in both the examples is the time between frames, so with 0.1 it would animate with 10 frames per second.

Here you can see and examples of it running:

https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Widgets_Sprite%20Animation%20Widget